# create `inteligent` apple mail reminders

Tags: mail.app, reminders

I am almost at 100% online Banking and Bill Pay.

Thus I get all my bills online in email.

Is there a way to extract the `due date and the amount` and place it in a reminder or calendar with reminder ect..

Or even more simple way....

Since I get bill mails almost exactly a Month in advance, can I just use the mail date and add 3 weeks to set the Reminder to that date.

Right now I just flag them, but then I have to frequently check that my self for due date.

However my Flagging them could it be used to trigger the action.

I tried Mail rules without success.

I am aware of drag and drop from Mail to Reminders, but it is a mindless operation.

I also tried Automator but stuck there with adding future date to reminders based on mail received date.

[image]

10.13.6

Comment: I made it work in Automator, will publish as answer soon.

Comment: Hello @Ruskes, could you make it work? Can you please share with us?