# Snooze mail in Apple Mail (set reminder for later)

Tags: mail.app, email, automator, reminders

I would like to snooze email in [mail.app](/questions/tagged/mail.app). I discovered that the easiest way is to set a reminder for certain mails to be (re)checked on a particular date which I can choose, using [automator](/questions/tagged/automator). I found a similar question but with no answer here: [create `inteligent` apple mail reminders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337682/create-inteligent-apple-mail-reminders)

I also got some help from this post & from the comments: [Build an Automator Quick Action To Snooze Email](https://macmost.com/build-an-automator-quick-action-to-snooze-email.html)
Based on it, I wanted to make reminders appear on Saturday, I get the following pop-up
[image]
but it returns error:
[image]

The javascript in [automator](/questions/tagged/automator)

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    
    // set up applications
    var Mail = Application("Mail");
    Mail.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    var Reminders = Application("Reminders");
    var SystemEvents = Application('System Events');
    
    // get the selected messages
    var messages = Mail.selection();
    
    // loop through all messages
    for(var i=0;i<messages.length;i++) {
    
        // get the subject, sender and message id
        var subject = messages[i].subject();
        var sender = messages[i].sender();
        var id = messages[i].messageId();
        
        // prompt for subject modifications and the snooze time
        var dialogResult = Mail.displayDialog('Email Snooze Reminder Title',
            { defaultAnswer: subject + ' from ' + sender,
            buttons: ['Until Saturday', '8 PM Today', 'Cancel'],
            defaultButton: 'Until Saturday',
            cancelButton: 'Cancel',
            withTitle: 'Mail Snooze' });

        // calculate the due date time
        var due = new Date();
        if (dialogResult.buttonReturned == 'Until Saturday') {
            var dueDay = 6;
            var diff = due.getDay() - dueDay;
            if (diff > 0) {
            due.setDate(due.getDate() + 6);
            } else if (diff < 0) {
                due.setDate(due.getDate() + ((-1)*diff))
            }

        } else if (dialogResult.buttonReturned == '8 PM Today') {
            due.setHours(20);
            due.setMinutes(0);
            due.setSeconds(0);
        } else {
            return; // cancelled, so quit
        }
        
        // get the new title
        reminderTitle = dialogResult.textReturned;
        
        // create a new reminder and add it
        var newReminder = Reminders.Reminder({ name: reminderTitle, body: "message://<"+id+">", dueDate: due});

        Reminders.lists.byName("Email Snooze").reminders.push(newReminder);
        
    }
        
    // send a Control+Command+a to archive the selected messages
    SystemEvents.keystroke('a', { using: ['control down', 'command down'] });
}
```

Seems like a very useful feature and I want not to move to 3rd party apps like Spark or Outlook just for this one. Can anyone help with this?